# Shut off valve for 2 refrigerator supply lines

Tags: plumbing

I need to run a refrigerator supply line for a new (additional) refrigerator that I just put in my basement.  I currently have a refrigerator supply line that runs from the basement up into the kitchen as you can see in the image below.  My original though was just to remove this valve and replace it with a shut-off that had 2 1/4" outlets, one outlet would attach to the existing line and the second I would connect to the new run.

The problem I have run into is that I can't find a valve that has dual 1/4" outlets, the best I could find is a valve with a 3/8" outlet and a 1/4" outlet.  I am guessing since I can't find a valve with 2 1/4" outlets there is something "wrong" with my approach.

I assume that the best way forward here would be to replace the current valve with a valve with 3/8" and 1/4" outlets, connect the current supply line to the 1/4" out and then run some 3/8" copper to the location where the new fridge is, and the put a 1/4" shutoff on the end of that run to actually connect the refrigerator supply line.

This feels "clunky" to me, although I am not a plumber so there might be a reason why I wouldn't want to split the line into 2 1/4" outlets.

Any advice on my approach here would be helpful, specifically is there a better way to do what I want to do?

[image]

Comment: If (as seems likely) not much flow is required, and rarely simeltaneously, a simple 1/4 inch tee would get you done. If you wanted to be overly concerned about pressure drop, which seems to me like "optimizing what won't matter" for this application, the 3/8 extension to near the other fridge would make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

No there is nothing wrong with your approach.

The reason you are finding 3/8 & 1/4 is that that is the most common configuration.

1 for the sink 3/8 and 1 for the fridge 1/4”.

Since it looks like ever is compression I might add a T and just add another valve.

I thought I had used a 3 port valve in the past on a 1/2” supply but a quick look I did not see one. So go with a t and add a valve and you have the same or adapt 3/8 to 1/4” 2 options.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a 1/2" MPT threaded end on the valve.  You should be able to go to any hardware store and get a 1/2" female/female/female tee, a 1/2" male nipple, and another valve like the one you have (and appropriate sealant or teflon tape).  That way you could connect a second valve to the same supply pipe.

Splitting after the valve will probably make zero difference to the real world performance since it's unlikely both supplies will be used at the same time.  It may not be strictly code-compliant, but it is probably what I would do.  You'll need something to cut a short length of copper tubing and a 1/4" flare tee (make sure it has the sleeve and nut for each end).  You'd run a single line out of the valve to the tee, and from the tee to each appliance.